# Can something be muktzeh to one person but not another?

Tags: shabbat, yom-tov, muktzeh, ownership

The question title says it all. In what sorts of cases, if any, could an item be muktzeh to one adult Jew but not to another?

If you [designate](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/47379/designating-muktzeh-items-before-shabbos-shabbat-for-personal-use) something for your own use before Shabbos, I think it may be not-muktzeh to you, but indeed muktzeh to others, for one thing. Also, medication that is essential for you but not others might  be permissible to you, but not them. The only other example I could think of--not knowing the laws of muktzeh very well--was an animal, which [may not](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/73483/is-my-dog-muktzeh-to-me-on-shabbos) be muktzeh to its owner(s) but almost certainly is to others.

But then I started to think: would animal feed also fall into this category? What about, l'havdil, certain people (someone else's baby? [Others](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/69191/what-to-do-if-your-husband-is-muktzeh)?)? I imagine there are probably other, less absurd examples, too. Are there? What are they?

Comment: in the medicine example, poskim say if it is useful for someone else in the vicinity it isn't muktzeh.

Comment: how would a baby be muktzeh? lets not mix purim torah and real torah...

Comment: you start by asking a yes or no question. you finish asking for a list. which one are you asking?

Comment: @mevaqesh I wasn't trying to. It's a fully serious question; "animal" led to "baby." I am pretty sure the baby isn't muktzeh, but why not, if animals not used for work are indeed muktzeh?

Comment: @mevaqesh They're not really mutually exclusive. Either the answer is no, and the list is "∅," or the answer is yes and the list contains some elements (Which?)

Comment: if you are sure the baby isnt mukseh then asking about it probably isnt a good idea, if you want to know why people cant be muktseh, consider asking separately.

Comment: I believe the gemara mentions that shards are not muktzeh since they are consumed by ostriches.  I believe the sense is that the case is not only involving ostrich owners. Also, I believe there is a more contemporary ruling that even those who keep the prohibition of reading newspapers on Shabbath are allowed to move them because of those who do read them.

Comment: Some people allow opening soda cans on Shabbat; others don't. Would that be an example?

Comment: @Loewian this seems like enough for an upvoted answer, if you can bring sources

Comment: @DanF according to Loewian it seems not

Comment: Perhaps a case where one makes food on shabbos, according to some opinions, the food is asur to the 'chef' but can be consumed by others.

Answer (score 6):

[Mishnah Berurah 308:170](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Berurah.308.171?lang=Bi) quotes [Taz Orach Chaim 308:25](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Turei_Zahav_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.308.25?lang=he) that small scraps of clothing are not *muktzeh* for a pauper, but are for a rich person (unless he lives in the pauper’s household).